# spring boot - why is @valid not working on controller for type?

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have Spring Boot application with a rest endpoint in a `@RestController` annotated class that is something like this:

```
@Postmapping(path = "<url>")
private @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> methodName(
    otherParameters otherParameters,
    @Valid @RequestBody Entity entity,
    Errors errors) {
if(errors.hasErrors()) {
    // log something
    // do something
}
// rest of the controller
}
```

The Entity class is something like this:

```
public class Entity {

@Pattern(regexp = "[^<>&]+")
private String someString;

// getters and setters
}
```

But when I try to reach the controller with `someString` as `some&tring`, the `@Valid` annotation does not seem to work.

This is accessible only from a rest call. There are no forms that use this action.

There is no spring-security implementation in this application at the moment.

What am I missing here?

Comment: i think you need anchors around your regex pattern if you want whole string not to includes any of these characters, i.e `^[^<>&]+$`

Comment: @CodeManiac, thanks, but it is still not working.

Comment: How are you submitting the data? Generally if you use a URL the stuff after the `&` is interpreted as a new parameter, unless you encode the `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: I got it working! The problem is that `Entity` has complex types and each needs a @Valid too, as per 'Use @Valid on Complex Types' from https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to add @Valid on the member fields of your pojos if those fields represent pojo's themselves, otherwise the validation does not propagate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the object add to the page.
check the following code.

check 1 :

// on controller side

```
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("entity", new Entity());
        return "registration";
    }

   @PostMapping("/registration")
   public String registration(@ModelAttribute("entity") Entity entity, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration"; // stay on that page here
        }
        return "login"; // after no error go here
   }
```

use this **entity** in form on the page where you want to access the validation

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${entity}" method="post" class="m-t">
```

check 2 :

```
both the get and post method must be the same name for the object created like **entity**
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, the controller is a rest api endpoint and there is no views with a `<form />` element that implement the action. I edited the original question to allow for better understanding.